# Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS Bluetooth not working, default adapter not found

Tags: bluetooth, 22.04

It seems the system can't find the default adapter. I've run the following commands. Hopefully, they will provide all the info required. If not, please ask, I'll post additional information.

```
sudo blueman-manager
blueman-manager 10.12.58 ERROR    Manager:137 on_dbus_name_appeared: Default adapter not found, trying first available.
blueman-manager 10.12.58 ERROR    Manager:141 on_dbus_name_appeared: No adapter(s) found, exiting
```

```
sudo bluetoothctl 
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# show
No default controller available
```

Hardware model: `ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC. ROG Zephyrus G15 GA503RW`

Processor: `AMD® Ryzen 9 6900hs with radeon graphics × 16`

Output for `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb; sudo dmesg | grep -i blue`:

```
pcilib: Error reading /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:08.3/label: Operation not permitted
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: MEDIATEK Corp. Device [14c3:0616]
    Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. Device [105b:e0cd]
    Kernel driver in use: mt7921e
    Kernel modules: mt7921e
Bus 009 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 010 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 13d3:56eb IMC Networks USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0489:e0e2 Foxconn / Hon Hai Wireless_Device
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0b05:19b6 ASUSTek Computer, Inc. ITE Device(8910)
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
[    3.640457] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    3.640501] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[    3.640504] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    3.640520] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    3.640523] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    3.640529] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    4.110285] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    4.110289] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    4.110295] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

Comment: Your title appears to have a wrong version number based with the tag you have used. You may want to correct this.

Comment: What is the hardware?

Comment: please indicate the correct version of Ubuntu. There is no 22.01.01 LTS https://www.releases.ubuntu.com/

Comment: My bad @24601, thanks.

Comment: I've edited the post to include my hardware model and processor @Pilot6.

Comment: Processor is not relevant is it a laptop using a built-in BT device? What is the BT adapter?

Comment: Yea @Pilot6, thats correct.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb; sudo dmesg | grep -i blue` terminal command.

Comment: There you go @Pilot6.

Comment: This device isn't supported by Ubuntu kernels. You can try a mainline kernel. https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?p=2219172&sid=95448aedc7738b9974a154a5765be4e1#p2219172

Comment: Alright @Pilot6, thanks for your time.

Comment: OMG @Pilot6, its working!!!! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Bluetooth adapter is not supported by Ubuntu kernels yet.

You can install a mainline kernel to get it working.

You can use [https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/) or another way. Kernel 6.0 should work.

Comment: Worked with mainline kernel v6.0 (Did not work for v5.19).

Answer (score -1):

Don't give up- **Persevere.**
I physically broke my little USB-Bluetooth adapter last week on my old Lenovo Thinkpad.
The old dongle is now a dangle. I managed to pry it out of the laptop's USB-port, and then ordered the least-expensive bluetooth adapter  I could find **on Amazon: The TP-Link UB400.  $9.**
I never thought of checking to see if it runs on Linux, until I plugged it in and the standard Bluetooth would not find any devices.
After reading all kinds of defeatist online comments- *"TP-Link  Bluetooth devices WILL NOT run on Ubuntu 22.04!"*, I eventually found an answer I liked.
So I installed **Blueman-manager 2.2.4 - (sudo apt install blueman)**  and THIS found my DOSS-Soundbox speaker, albeit as "headphones".
I have yet to dual boot the laptop into Win-10 and try the UB400 there.  Gee.. I sure hope **it's supported in Windows!  ;-)**

Comment: How does this answer the question?